# Using reflection to find all Classes of a Type(), ordering them, and invoking a named method

Tags: c#, reflection, entity-framework-core

I have taken a leaf out of EFC and tried to develop something similar to `modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly()` for SQL commands that I need to run against my database in a specific order.

I would like to invoke all the methods of any class where that class inherits from my `Interface`.  But I want to invoke them in groups or orders.

My interface is:

```
public interface IDatabaseSqlCommands
{
    public ExecutionGroups ExecutionGroup { get; }
    public Task Configure(DbContext context);
}
```

An example nested class is:

```
private sealed class SqlCommands : IDatabaseSqlCommands
{
    public ExecutionGroups ExecutionGroup { get; } = ExecutionGroups.G1;

    public async Task Configure(DbContext ctx)
    {
        await ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(
        @"
            CREATE TRIGGER Customers_Timestamp
            AFTER UPDATE ON Customers
            BEGIN
                UPDATE Customers
                SET Version = Version + 1
                WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;
            END 
        ");
    }
}
```

So using `System.Reflection` I am able to find the interface and invoke the interface by using:

```
public async Task EnsureSqlCreatedAsync()
{
    // We are only interested in non-abstact private nested classes which are sealed
    var classCollection = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                            .DefinedTypes.Where(
                                t => !t.IsAbstract &&
                                t.IsClass &&
                                t.IsSealed &&
                                t.IsNestedPrivate);

    foreach (var type in classCollection)
    {
        // Class must have an empty constructor
        if (type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) == null)
            continue; // Constructor is not empty

        foreach (var @interface in type.GetInterfaces())
        {
            if (@interface.GetTypeInfo() == typeof(IDatabaseSqlCommands))
            {
                var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                await ((IDatabaseSqlCommands)instance).Configure(this);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So that all works fine, and all the instances get invoked, but what I now want to do is

1. find all the classes that have that Interface; and
2. invoke `Configure()` by the order of ExecutionGroup

The definition of `ExecutionGroups` is:

```
public enum ExecutionGroups
{
    G1=1, G2=2, G3=3, G4=4, G5=6
}
```

I can't work out the Linq to order my classes by the value of ExecutionGroup so that my Sql executes in order of dependency.

Comment: just append an `OrderBy(x => x.ExecutionGroup)` after your LINQ-query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your loop into LINQ query like this (and do the ordering right there too):

```
var commands = classCollection
    .Where(type => 
        type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null &&
        type.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.GetTypeInfo() == typeof(IDatabaseSqlCommands)))
    .Select(type => (IDatabaseSqlCommands) Activator.CreateInstance(type))
    .OrderBy(c => c.ExecutionGroup);
foreach (var command in commands) {
    await command.Configure(this);
}
```